# How to set a public LB route to a proxy on AWS?

Tags: ssl, amazon-vpc, route, amazon-alb

I built this traffic route in a VPC.

```
Route53->ACM(SSL)->Public ALB->EC2(Nginx proxy)->Private ALB->ECS(Internal App)
```

The EC2's security group is allowing tcp 80 and 443. The ECS' security group is allowing 80 from EC2's security group.

When I access the domain registered in Route53, it got `504 DNS look up failed` error.
When access the public ALB's DNS name got `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` error.

I'm sure the ACM is setting and the public LB's DNS name is registering to the Route53 with the domain.

The ALB settings on the public subnet are doing by Terraform

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.this.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "http_redirect" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.proxy.arn
  priority     = 1

  action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/*"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "http_forward" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 2

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.proxy.arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["proxy.portsite.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "https_forward" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.https.arn

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.proxy.arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["proxy.portsite.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

Are both `http_redirect` and `http_forward` necessary for the routing? Or only `http_redirect` is good?
And, does the issue caused by it?

Comment: the last two ressources: "aws_lb_listener_rule" "https_forward" seems the same (except the prio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect rule are used to force http to http**S**.

To send traffic to a backend you need to use the **forward** action.

You can check the HTTP "Server" header to know who is sending the 503 error (either the ALB, nginx, ECS, ...)

*The ECS' security group is allowing 80 from EC2's security group.* :
ECS security group must allow the private ALB.
the private ALB security group must allow the EC2 instance

Comment: Thank you for answer. The 503 error came from the public ALB's DNS name. Like `proxy-1130301830.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. The ECS sg is allowing the private ALB and the private ALB sg is allowing the IP of EC2.

Comment: I found the target group is unhealthy. I set the EC2's IP to it directly. EC2 is in the private subnet, the target group is in the public subnet's ALB. So they can't communicate?
- https://imgur.com/a/7Crag5l
- https://imgur.com/a/gf0hmzq